# How to compile opencv with imcodecs?

Tags: c++, opencv, png, jpeg

So to expand, i've been failing to write image to file and i've read in the documentation that i need to cmake with the correct flags, however there is no mention of which flag i need to use and what to make it equal.

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the specified extension) in imwrite_, file /home/User/Desktop/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp, line 45
```

Now what i've been running is

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/User/Desktop/opencv_contrib/modules WITH_PNG WITH_JPEG CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

with the extra **WITH_PNG** and **WITH_JPEG** flags which compile normally but i get the same problem when running my code, so i assume these are wrong.

durring the build this was the output i recieved

```
.
.
.
Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.50)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.3)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
.
.
.
```

So from what i understand of this is that the error suggests that it is looking the wrong place? but i have not the slightest of clues.

To clarify i can read images i just cant save Mats to a file, i've tried to convert it to CV_16UC1 and CV_8UC1 but still have the same issue, the program exits with the openCV error.

I've tried jpg jpeg bmp, none seem to work.

I am running linux mint rosa with opencv 3.1 freshly downloaded from git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a typo that the compiler wasn't able to pick up, most likely because i was concatenating strings together before passing in the path to the imwrite.

When defining the path, i accidentally used

```
const String folderName="PATH"
```

when i actually meant

```
const string folderName="PATH"
```

Note the difference between **string** and **String**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not with OpenCV build (I am 100% sure it is able to save images without 3rd party components) but probably permissions to create/write file or something wrong with destination path. Make sure path exists.

Comment: so the path definitely exists since im making a system call just before it to create the folder and the folder is definitely getting created every time.To check this i've added a static path and still nothing. regarding permission assume this were true, how would i go about giving my program permissions to save to somewhere within my home dir? I assume since im running it i have access.

Comment: Debug and find that exactly is going wrong inside OpenCV. Before it throws Abort.

Comment: Also try chmod 777 on output folder just to make sure anyone can do anything inside that folder.

Comment: Tried both neither worked, but i did find my answer it was my fault, thank you anyways, if it was also a permission fault its fixed now thanks to you. The debugger didnt catch any errors but terminated at the imwrite line, which was very weird.